# I using mvc:resource mapping to map resources

Tags: spring-mvc

Ok under my web root I have placed all resources js, css, images in a folder, then in my app-context.xml I put the mvc:resources annotation.

```
webroot
   ...
   layout
      js
      css
      images
```

the problem is third party libs look for resources of the root and they can't be found, even if I place an images folder of the root,

Comment: Your static resources will have a different prefix then the context path. I think your best bet is to modify the 3rd party libs to look elsewhere.

Comment: Moding the 3rd party lib doesn't work I had to copy the css into my jsp to get it to work. I checked that the 3rd party css was loaded using the js debugger. Well working now thought there was another way. Thanks for the reply